# How to apply same html bg color to all columns using Pandas to_html

Tags: python, html, pandas, sed

I have been trying to get the same background color applied to all cells in the same row based on an identifier data.

For example:

[image]

How can I make the entire row the same color? Right now just the date column is colored.

I am using `df.to_html()` and then `sed`:

```
sed -i 's@<td>2020-08-31<\/td>@<td bgcolor="grey">2020-08-31<\/td>@g' <file>
sed -i 's@<td>2020-09-01<\/td>@<td bgcolor="#F49884">2020-09-01<\/td>@g' <file>
```

I'm open to using `sed`/`awk` or Python.

Comment: Here you are defining how the table must be displayed, this is what CSS is used for. By default the html table generated by pandas is assigned the class `dataframe` which can be used in a CSS selector (and you can customize the instance further using `to_html()` parameters if you need). If you can add an inline or external CSS section in your html page (with a rule like `table.dataframe td { background-color: red }`), then I'd suggest to do so instead of modifying the markup (especially with tools not designed to parse the complex structure of html).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Python with `.replace()`.

Pandas `to_html()` just returns an html string representing a dataframe. You can then use any Python string manipulation on the resulting string.

For example:

```
def add_bg_color(html, identifier):
    return html.replace(
        f"<td>{identifier}<\/td>", 
        f"<td background-color='grey'>{identifier}<\/td>"
    )
```

Use it like this:

```
html = df.to_html()
add_bg_color(html, '2020-08-31')
```

Note I also changed `bgcolor` to `background-color` which is the proper CSS property name.